# How change the active field to inactive keeping the value of the field intact using golang?

Tags: json, go

I have the following json structure for image:

```
 {"image": [
  {
    "bytesize": "-2",
    "default": "redlight_drdefault"
  },
  {
    "active": "JV77tdMcHkChFaF2H9uoDHepPhUcrlprYEsQr-r-1lg=",
    "bytesize": "566806"
  }
]}
```

I want to change the the field named "active" to "inactive" without changing the value stored in the field like the following:

```
    {"image": [
  {
    "bytesize": "-2",
    "default": "redlight_drdefault"
  },
  {
    "inactive": "JV77tdMcHkChFaF2H9uoDHepPhUcrlprYEsQr-r-1lg=",
    "bytesize": "566806"
  }
]}
```

Do anyone has the solution how to do this??If u can show this on playground it will be great.

I am having difficulty in appending new value which is:

```
    mapactive := map[string]string{"active": "gj65vn768=", 
    "bytesize":"76878768" }
```

How to append this to the solutions provided to me???This should be appended at the end of making all active keys inactive.

Comment: Use `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: I have tried but not able to do this

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Golang allows direct conversion between structures that are identical in types, even if they differ in field tags.  That is, you can convert directly between:

```
type Active struct {
    Active   string `json:"active"`
    ByteSize string `json:"bytesize"`
}
```

and

```
type Inactive struct {
    Active string `json:"inactive"`
    ByteSize string `json:"bytesize"`
}
```

Using the following:

```
var a Active
// decode JSON into a
var b Inactive = Inactive(a) // direct conversion allowed
```

*However*, your input JSON won't easily support this.  Your input JSON is listing the `image` field as a *list*, despite the various entries in the list not actually being identical in type or fields.  The only real option in that case is to parse it as a nested set of `map[string]interface{}`:

https://play.golang.org/p/4NgiKLlHg8c

```
parsed := make(map[string]interface{})
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &parsed); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

img, ok := parsed["image"]
if ok {
    if imglist, ok := img.([]interface{}); ok {
        for i, mi := range imglist {
            if m, ok := mi.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
                for k, v := range m {
                    if k == "active" {
                        m["inactive"] = v
                        delete(m, "active")
                        imglist[i] = m
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

b, err := json.Marshal(img)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Note that I've removed a lot of sanity checks from this code to make it shorter and more readable.  Using nested interface maps for handling JSONs is inherently messy.  If you *can* change how the input JSON is formatted, you'll have a *lot* better luck, and more easily maintainable code, by doing so.

Comment: I don't think the first type can convert each other. Can you provide a playground link?

Comment: This does [not compile](https://play.golang.org/p/aC7uus_8tga): `cannot convert a (type Active) to type Inactive`. I think you're confusing structs and interfaces?

Comment: Crap, sorry, you're right, they have to have the same field names.  Updated answer, _does_ compile now: https://play.golang.org/p/CeyNHo9KVrf

Comment: Thanks @Kaedys for ur help.I have fixed all my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with predefined structures. https://play.golang.org/p/Y3xpESlbbN3

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type (
    images struct {
        Image []image `json:"image"`
    }

    image struct {
        Active string `json:"active,omitempty"`
        common
    }

    newImages struct {
        Image []newImage `json:"image"`
    }

    newImage struct {
        common
        Inactive string `json:"inactive,omitempty"`
    }

    common struct {
        Bytesize string `json:"bytesize"`
        Default  string `json:"default,omitempty"`
    }
)

var i = []byte(`
 {"image": [
  {
    "bytesize": "-2",
    "default": "redlight_drdefault"
  },
  {
    "active": "JV77tdMcHkChFaF2H9uoDHepPhUcrlprYEsQr-r-1lg=",
    "bytesize": "566806"
  }
]}
`)

func main() {

    var images images
    e := json.Unmarshal(i, &images)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    var newImages newImages
    for k, _ := range images.Image {

        newImg := newImage{}
        if len(images.Image[k].Active) > 0 {
            newImg.Inactive = images.Image[k].Active
        }
        newImg.Default = images.Image[k].Default
        newImg.Bytesize = images.Image[k].Bytesize
        newImages.Image = append(newImages.Image, newImg)

    }

    result, e := json.Marshal(newImages)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(result))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    var x S

    json.Unmarshal(data,&x)
    for _,img:=range x.Image {
        Deactive(img)
    }


    b,_:=json.Marshal(x)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

type S struct {
    Image []map[string]interface{} `json:"image"`
}

func Deactive(x map[string]interface{}) {
    if v,ok := x["active"]; ok {
        delete(x,"active")
        x["inactvie"]=v
    }
}

var data = []byte(` {"image": [
  {
    "bytesize": "-2",
    "default": "redlight_drdefault"
  },
  {
    "active": "JV77tdMcHkChFaF2H9uoDHepPhUcrlprYEsQr-r-1lg=",
    "bytesize": "566806"
  }
]}
`)
```

As I said, use `map[string]interface{}`. But put it as deep as possible in the nested structure for it is messy and tricky.

The `Deactive` takes in the map and looks for an `active` key, if there is one, it will take the value, insert an `inactive` key with that value, and delete `actvie`.